# Why does gcloud build insist on making new PIP packages each time?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have `Google Cloud SDK 469.0.0, alpha 2024.03.15, beta 2024.03.15, bq 2.1.1, core 2024.03.15, gsutil 5.27`

I read on multiple Stackoverflow posts that if I structure my Dockerfile as

```
FROM python:3.12
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY requirements.txt ./ 
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
COPY . ./

[CMD]
```

then Dockerfile will cache the pip installations and not keep repeating them each time I change the source code.

This doesn't seem to work with `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/...`

Is there some setting that I should be applying?

Comment: Presumably those builds get built on fresh VMs with no cached layers.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Cloud Build can cache between build steps, but each build starts fresh. What do you mean by **making new PIP packages**? If you mean to download the source code and compile it, that is a package issue (design decision) that the maintainer made, review their documentation as to why.

Comment: page after page of this kind of thing:
Downloading pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
103.2/103.2 kB 12.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
229.9/229.9 kB 24.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Downloading tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (345 kB)
345.4/345.4 kB 31.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading Brotli-1.1.0-cp312-cp312-

Comment: Docker allows you to do one line for the PIP installs by copying just requirements.txt to the work directory, then after that build you copy all the files and keep going. The result is a docker layer that has all of the Pip work and a second layer than builds on top by adding the source code. I see online some mention of gcloud Kinoki that may help.

Answer (score 0):

So gcloud does indeed have an option to store partial layers, Google called it the Kaniko cache. I chose 8hrs as the time-to-live for the PIP packages. All I needed to do was set two configuration parameters:

```
gcloud config set builds/use_kaniko True
gcloud config set builds/kaniko_cache_ttl 8
```

In my case I have not just `requirements.txt` but I also want to Cythonize something, so I put all of that before `COPY . ./`, Thus

```
COPY requirements.txt   setup_pyd.py CoreLoop.pyx  ./ 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup_pyd.py build_ext --inplace --include-dir=/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/include
COPY . ./
```

And perfect, now as long as `requirements.txt` doesn't change then all of the packages are installed in a cache that gcloud can use to build the next level.

I then just run `gcloud build submit --tag  gcr.io/xxx/yyy` as before.